# Symfony2 validation of OneToMany ArrayCollection of Image entities

Tags: php, image, validation, symfony, doctrine-orm

I am facing a problem with validation of new uploaded file.

I have my Product entity:

```
// src/Acme/DemoBundle/Entity/Product
...
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Image", mappedBy="product", cascade={"persist"})
 * @Assert\Image(
 *     minWidth = 10,
 *     maxWidth = 20,
 *     minHeight = 10,
 *     maxHeight = 20
 * )
 */
protected $images;
...
public function __construct()
{
    $this->images= new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
}
public function getImages(){
    return $this->images;
}

public function setImages($images){
    $this->images = $images;

    return $this;
}
```

Image entity is a very simple, with name, size, mimetype.

And I have working on some custom upload listener, so I am not using form and form->isValid. I validate like this:

```
...
public function onUpload(PostPersistEvent $event)
{
        $em= $this->doctrine->getManager();
        $product = $this->doctrine->getRepository('Acme\DemoBundle\Entity\Product')->findOneById($customId);

        $image = new Image();
        $image->setProduct($product)
               ->setName($uploadInfo->name)
               ->setStoredName($uploadInfo->storedName)
               ->setUuid($uploadInfo->uuid)
               ->setSize($uploadInfo->size)
               ->setMimeType($uploadInfo->mimeType);

        $validator = Validation::createValidatorBuilder()
        ->enableAnnotationMapping()
        ->getValidator();

        $a = $product->getImages();
        $a->add($image);
        $product->setImages($a);

        $errors = $validator->validate($product);
```

And I've got an error:

```
{"message":"Expected argument of type string, object given","class":"Symfony\\Component\\Validator\\Exception\\UnexpectedTypeException","trace":[{"namespace":"","short_class":"","class":"","type":"","function":"","file":".../vendor\/symfony\/symfony\/src\/Symfony\/Component\/Validator\/Constraints\/FileValidator.php","line":98,"args":[]}
```

If let say I do NotNull annotation Assert on enother field (like name) - it works, I can get errors. But with ArrayCollection - is not.

I am doing something wrong and can't find info in the internet.

Could the gurus help me out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To validate collection you can use [All](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/All.html) and [Valid](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Valid.html) validators.

```
Acme\DemoBundle\Entity\Product:
    properties:
        images:
            - Valid: ~
            - All:
                - NotNull: ~

Acme\DemoBundle\Entity\Image:
    properties:
        file:
            - Image:
                minWidth: 200
                maxWidth: 400
                minHeight: 200
                maxHeight: 400
```

Comment: I've added

     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Image", mappedBy="product", cascade={"persist"})
     * @Assert\All({
     *     @Assert\Image(
     *         minWidth = 10,
     *         maxWidth = 20,
     *         minHeight = 10,
     *         maxHeight = 20
     *     )
     * })
     protected $images;

Nothing changed.

And I don't have a $file property, why have you added it?

Comment: Ok. I found it out. I've added the property 'file'. Set the UploadedFile or File on it. And validation is works. Thx